# I need a very simple way for my VB.NET program to 'phone home' (i.e. send a simple message)

Tags: vb.net

I used to get it to send an email, but this seems to only work half of the time.

I just need a relatively fail-safe way to send a ~20KB plain text message to somewhere I, the developer, can access on the Internet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to determine _why_ emailing fails so often? Consider tackling that before trying something more complicated (like posting to a web method or uploading via ftp...)

Comment: Do you have a web server on which you could set up a web service to accomplish the task?

Comment: Based on what you describe, this should help you:
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15299/Send-a-Text-Message-to-a-Cell-Phone-from-a-VB-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15299/Send-a-Text-Message-to-a-Cell-Phone-from-a-VB-NET)

Comment: I don't have access to a web server. Around 1/3 of the time, the email sends OK and the rest of the time, I get a 'Must issue a STARTTLS command' error. I tried the various fixes on the net, but none completely fixed the issue. I thought with all of the free online dev tools, there must be one that could help.

Comment: Is the software a single instance that is unable to reliable send an email? Or is this something like a one off software registration where some sites are unable to send emails at all?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of pastebin and other text hosting websites. Privacy is not really an issue.

Comment: It is software I distribute to less than 5 people. It is not about software registration – I just want to know what its being used for and when.

Comment: I develop an application in a manufacturing environment and use a Gmail account to send myself emails at various times via SMTP. Is this different from what you have tried?

Comment: This is what I've tried. I have had a look at Pastebin's api and I think I will do it this way.

Comment: As @Oded has said, maybe you should figure out why emails fail so often. It's possible you will experience the same issues with the Pastebin solution.

Comment: I can't figure it out, but using the Pastebin API is very different and it works well now. It's just a http post, so no vague smtp errors.